# Contact form field in wordpress menu

Tags: php, menus, shortcode

I am trying to insert a simple 1 field contact 7 form into my menu.

I have this code working for just text, but if I try to insert the shortcode for the form, I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 8, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary')  {
    $items .= '<li class="menu-item">Text goes here</li>';
}
return $items;
}
```

Here I try to insert shortcode for form:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 8, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary')  {
    $items .= '<li class="menu-item">echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1323" title="Newsletter"]' );</li>';
}
return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're getting error, because your code is not correct... There is syntax error in this line (You combine string and PHP code in there...):

```
$items .= '<li class="menu-item">echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1323" title="Newsletter"]' );</li>';
```

It should look like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 8, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary')  {
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item">'. do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1323" title="Newsletter"]' ) .'</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not very comfortable with my PHP.